# Angular provide service created at parent component's viewProviders in child component's viewProviders

Tags: angular, typescript, web-frontend

Let's say I have a parent component `AppComponent`, a directive `MyDrective` and a service `SimpleService`

`MyDirective` is used at `AppComponent`'s template and inject `SimpleService` with `Host` decorator, since I don't want to use the instance from `AppComponent`'s parent,
so I create a new instance at `AppComponent`'s `viewProviders`.

But now I have a `HelloComponent` which is a child of `AppComponent`, `HelloComponent` use `MyDirective` too, but this time I want the `MyDirective` inside `HelloComponent` use the sample instance of `SimpleService` from `AppComponent`, how should I do?

I have tried `{provide: SimpleService, useExisting: SimpleService}`, but this leads to cyclic dependency error.

sample code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7h352z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this decorator to your service
`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})`

This should create singleton instance of this service.

Comment: I don't want a singleton instance, I want an instance shared only by `AppComponent` and `HelloComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Use providers property so it's av provider available to its content children and view children.

**Try this:**

```
providers: [{provide: SimpleService, useValue: SimpleService }]
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ym1rmy)

Answer (score 0):

use in constructor @SkipSelf()

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `child <input myDirective >{{value}}`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  viewProviders: [SimpleService]

})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor(@Host() @Optional() @SkipSelf() private simpleService: SimpleService) {}
  value:any
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.value=this.simpleService?this.simpleService.message:"No service"
  }
}
```

NOTE:If you want to get both: you can inject the own service as

```
  constructor(
     @Host() @Optional() @SkipSelf() private simpleService: SimpleService
     private simpleServiceChild:SimpleService
   ) {}
```